# Sites which support crossdomain.xml to allow Flash and Silverlight access

Tags: flash, silverlight

Please list **one** site which allows Flash/Silverlight access via crossdomain.xml file. Vote for your favorite sites.

The goal is to build an up to date list of sites which can be directly accessed via Flash/Silverlight without a server-side proxy.

Comment: Hint: there's a list here, but who knows how up to date it is - http://ha.ckers.org/weird/crossdomain.html

Comment: A lot of these only allow access from subdomains or specific domains.

Comment: Yep - I've been going through them and noticing the same thing.

Comment: Dan, I enabled wiki mode

Comment: Java now supports crossdomain.xml too so unsigned applets can access resources on other domains that allow it in the same way as flash. From java 6 update 10 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The feeds a [http://www.feedburner.com](http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/home) are accessable via the [CrossDomain](http://feeds.feedburner.com/crossdomain.xml) file. All rss feeds can be read with Silverlight.

(This may help the search a bit: [googlesearch](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=filetype%3Axml+crossdomain))

Answer (score 3):

Flickr's got one here:

http://api.flickr.com/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 1):

Photobucket.com:
http://api.photobucket.com/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 1):

http://services.digg.com/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 1):

http://flash-world.ru/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 1):

Flash can be 'hacked' into consuming web services from any domain by using the browser's less-restrictive security model instead of Flash's security model.

I wrote one in ActionScript 3 and passes JSON to the browser with a callback return a native JSON object back to Flash. No server-proxy or external javascript needed.

JSONP.as - http://gist.github.com/1204728

In ActionScript call:

```
JSONP.get("http://api.twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json", 
        "{screen_name:'puppybits', count:'1'}", 
         function(data):void{ 
          trace('flash received cross-domain json:'+data)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Pipes (http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) allow access to a lot of pages and feeds that don't have crossdomain.xml files. It'll access just any page which allows indexing (robots.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SimpleDB does NOT currently support crossdomain.xml or clientaccesspolicy.xml... it is huge FAIL in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

http://johndyer.name/crossdomain.xml is open.

Jon, how do you use Yahoo Pipes from Silverlight, since its crossdomain.xml is restrictive ?